# How to Move the listener area of a View in ViewAnimation

Tags: android, android-animation, objectanimator

In my android app, I have a checkbox layout which will be slide up and down from the center of screen.Though I'm using Object Animator When I check true to Check box, the check box layout moves down and if I uncheck the layout should move up. My Issue is check box moves down when I select it. But I can't select the checkbox when it is down. Instead if I click on the center(i.e previous checkbox position) it slides up to center. So It moves only the View part, not listener part. I'm using following code to animate

### Checkbox Layout view

```
mChkView = findViewById(R.id.chkbx_layout_id);
```

### Animator code

```
ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mChkView, "translationY", 0, 60).setDuration(0).start();
```

I have found several answers in stack over flow as listed :

[Answer Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10262876/view-animation-doesnt-change-touch-area)

[Answer Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14011150/touch-area-doesnt-move-after-translate-animation)

[Answer Link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10141244/android-please-explain-how-to-properly-move-a-view)

[Answer Link4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6535648/how-can-i-dynamically-set-the-position-of-view-in-android)

But none of the answer helps me.

Comment: reduce the size of y2 of your translatoranimation then it will work.

Comment: I'm using ObjectAnimator class

Comment: can you post your code

Comment: UIView is part of UIKit which is a framework for iOS. The `uiviewanimation` tag was removed since this is a question about Andriod.

Comment: reduce 60 to 50 or less.

Comment: what is the code for it

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ObjectAnimator mover = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(aniView,
              "translationX", -500f, 0f);
          mover.setDuration(2000);
```

-500f and 0f are the float value of the position from and to . Set these two value according to your need.

Hope this helps.